# show / hide table columns using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with five columns

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
------- ------- ------- ------- -------
```

and I have some check boxes each one for one column when the first checkbox is checked 
   then I need to show the first column , if unchecked I need to hide first column. Like that
   I need to do for all columns.

I found some  answers but I did not find any solution .First time it is hiding then other 
   operations are not working on that.

```
 $('#tableId td:nth-child(column number)').hide();
```

Please help me .Thanks in advance....

Comment: It would be great if you include some html please

Comment: Use classes on your `td`s if you're using an actual HTML Table

Comment: what is not working? Can we see the code?

Comment: i used above code.First time it is working.But from second time it is not working

Comment: Just FYI, updated my answer to give you full explination of what is going on and the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/FyMRy/) included show EXACTLY what you're asking here at work

Comment: Also, just gave you an alternate idea that might help toward your end result. it's pretty clean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go, full solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/vXBtP/

and updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/vXBtP/5/

```
<table>
   <thead>
       <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>column 1</td>
        <td>column 2</td>
        <td>column 3</td>
        <td>column 4</td>
        <td>column 5</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

$(document).on('change', 'table thead input', function() {
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked");

    var index = $(this).parent().index();
    if(checked) {
        $('table tbody tr td').eq(index).show();
    } else {
        $('table tbody tr td').eq(index).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: actually i have checkboxes outside to the table

Comment: Wherever they are, you just need them in a container, then .index() will still work. So the above example will still work even if you have all <input> inside a <div>.

Comment: @Chris What if there are colspan in table heading?

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the column # you wanna hide, use this stolen one liner:

```
$('td:nth-child(2)').hide();
```

if you use th

```
$('td:nth-child(2),th:nth-child(2)').hide();
```

Comment: I just saw more info in your question, looks like you tried this. You will need to specify the table like you did in your question, but this should work.

Answer (score 3):

If I got what you mean, you can make it real simple using `tr th, tr td` and `nth-child` selector. You can go based on index, but you'll need to add 1 as `nth-child` is not 0 indexed like elements in jQuery. And the JS doesn't really have to be drawn out. I should mention, placing `tr` before `td:nth` is very important in that you don't want "only the nth td". if that's the case, you won't hide every col on every row.

## See WORKING jsFIDDLE of YOUR Example

---

FYI: If you want something "cleaner" looking, (like on the turbotax site) **dont** hide the td itself. Instead make it slightly wider than your largest piece of text, and place each piece of text inside `p` or `div` tags inside each cell. Then change you `column` selector to grab each cell's **inner** element and hide that instead.

### See Example of this Alternate way here!

---

#### HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input id="chk1" type="checkbox" />
            </th>
            <th>
                <input id="chk1" type="checkbox" />
            </th>
            <th>
                <input id="chk1" type="checkbox" />
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                col1
            </td>
            <td>
                col2
            </td>
            <td>
                col3
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                col1
            </td>
            <td>
                col2
            </td>
            <td>
                col3
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                col1
            </td>
            <td>
                col2
            </td>
            <td>
                col3
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                col1
            </td>
            <td>
                col2
            </td>
            <td>
                col3
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button>Reset</button>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    //  Selects your table by id, then the input checkboxes inside the table, you can 
    //  alternate this call with classnames on your inputs if you're going to have 
    //  more inputs than what's desired in call here.
        //  also note i'm using the "change" function and not "click", this simply 
        //  provides easier control of what's going on with your inputs and makes 
        //  later calls (like reset) a much easier call. Less thinking required
    $("#tableId input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function(e) {
        //  First variable grabs the inputs PARENT index, this is the TH containing 
        //  the input, thus the column you want hidden.
        //  The second is calling ALL TH's && TD's having that same index number
        var id = $(this).parent().index()+1,
            col = $("table tr th:nth-child("+id+"), table tr td:nth-child("+id+")");
        //  This simple inline "if" statement checks if the input is checked or now
        //  and shows the columns based on if it IS checked
        $(this).is(":checked") ? col.show() : col.hide();
    }).prop("checked", true).change(); // here i set all inputs to checked without having to write it in the above HTML

    $("button").on("click", function(e) {
        $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true).change();
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the header index of table and make the table header and td elements hidden. Something like this 
 Suppose the index of table header is index = 2;

```
var index= tableHeaderIndex; // 2 here

$('th:nth-child('+index+')').hide();
$('td:nth-child('+index+')').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Like [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/PottyMonster/YeFm5/)

Lashed together quickly but should work.

```
<table id="TabToHide">
    <tr>
        <td class="Col1">Col 1</td>
        <td class="Col2">Col 2</td>
        <td class="Col3">Col 3</td>
        <td class="Col4">Col 4</td>
        <td class="Col5">Col 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Col1">Stuff 1</td>
        <td class="Col2">Stuff 2</td>
        <td class="Col3">Stuff 3</td>
        <td class="Col4">Stuff 4</td>
        <td class="Col5">Stuff 5</td>
    </tr>    
</table>

<br />

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="Col1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
        <td><input name="Col2" type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
        <td><input name="Col3" type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
        <td><input name="Col4" type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
        <td><input name="Col5" type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
   $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
   var ColToHide = $(this).attr("name");    
    if(this.checked){
        $("td[class='" + ColToHide + "']").show();        
    }else{
        $("td[class='" + ColToHide + "']").hide();
    }

    $('div#Debug').text("hiding " + ColToHide);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tr input:checkbox').change(function(){
        var num = $(this).parents("th").index(); 
        alert(num);
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {

            $('table tbody tr td').eq(num).show();   
        }else
        {
            $('table tbody tr td').eq(num).hide(); 
        }

    });
});
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/t6V6J/5/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Show and Hide Columns in a Table</title>
    <link href="CSS/table.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var $chk = $("#grpChkBox input:checkbox");
            var $tbl = $("#someTable");
            $chk.prop('checked', true);
            $chk.click(function () {
                var colToHide = $tbl.find("." + $(this).attr("name"));
                $(colToHide).toggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Show and Hide Columns in a Table</h2>
    <p>Click on each Checkbox to hide corresponding Column</p>
    <div id="grpChkBox">
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="empid" /> Employee ID</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="fname" /> First Name</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="lname" /> Last Name</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="email" /> Email</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="phone" /> Phone</p>
    </div>

    <table id="someTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="empid">EmpId</th>
                <th class="fname">First Name</th>
                <th class="lname">Last Name</th>
                <th class="email">Email</th>
                <th class="phone">Phone</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="empid">E342</td>
                <td class="fname">Bill</td>
                <td class="lname">Evans</td>
                <td class="email">Bill@devcurry.com</td>
                <td class="phone">234-2345-2345</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="empid">E343</td>
                <td class="fname">Laura</td>
                <td class="lname">Matt</td>
                <td class="email">laura@devcurry.com</td>
                <td class="phone">123-1234-5678</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="empid">E344</td>
                <td class="fname">Ram</td>
                <td class="lname">Kumar</td>
                <td class="email">ram@devcurry.com</td>
                <td class="phone">345-3456-7890</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an "id" on your "th" element and simply call:
$('#yourId').hide();

here is the code I've utilized :

```js
$(document).on('click', '.form-check-input', function(e){
  var finition_checked =  $('#finition_select[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){
    return $(this).prop('checked');
  }).get();
  var size_checked = $('#size_select[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){
    return $(this).prop('checked');
  }).get();
  if (finition_checked && size_checked.length === 0){
    $('#price-container').hide();
    $('.table-responsive').show();
    $('#col_size').hide();
  };
  if (finition_checked.length === 0 && size_checked){
    $('#price-container').hide();
    $('.table-responsive').show();
    $('#col_finition').hide();
  };
  if(size_checked && finition_checked){
    $('#price-container').hide();
    $('.table-responsive').show();
  }
  if(size_checked.length === 0 && finition_checked.length === 0){
    $('#price-container').show();
    $('.table-responsive').hide();
  };
  console.log(finition_checked, size_checked)
  var unique_value = [];
  var finition = [];
  var size = [];
  //more logic to come


});
```