# How to hide column in HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML table which i am rendering from JSON data i have three `headers` row  first one is showing `total` and `Outlets` which are  `jayanagar`,`Malleshwaram` and `Kolar`, second one is showing the Amount Type which are `Gross Amount`, `Discount`, `GST` and `Net Amount` and third one is showing there respective amount column wise and then the table body which is showing full data

What i am trying to do is:-

- I have an input field with drop-down which as checkbox to select multiple options
- the select box are `Amount Type` like `Gross Amount`, `Discount`, `GST` and `Net Amount` and there is one button `Go`
- So when user clicks on `Go` after selecting options what i am trying to do is to show only that column what user has selected

**My Table code**

```js
$(".checkbox-menu").on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function() { // this one to select multiple options as check box
  $(this).closest("li").toggleClass("active", this.checked);
  var sList = "";
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      sList += $(this).val() + ","
    }
  });

  $("#To").val(sList.slice(0, -1));
});

$(document).on('click', '.allow-focus', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

var data = [{
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 490465,
    "discount": 839,
    "GST": 28465,
    "amount": 518212
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 99212,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 5567,
    "amount": 104801
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 131349,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 6676,
    "amount": 138151
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 594466,
    "discount": 591,
    "GST": 34374,
    "amount": 628358
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 109029,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 6062,
    "amount": 115113
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 127449,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 6511,
    "amount": 134107
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-06",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 167811,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 9968,
    "amount": 177866
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-06",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 62796,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3257,
    "amount": 66095
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 267398,
    "discount": 268,
    "GST": 15898,
    "amount": 283124
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 55381,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3383,
    "amount": 58789
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 64586,
    "discount": 6,
    "GST": 3285,
    "amount": 67886
  }
]

let formatData = function(data) {
  let billdates = [];
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
      billdates.push(element.billdate);
    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  return {
    data: data,
    billdates: billdates,
    outlets: outlets,

  };
};

let renderTable = function(data) {
  billdates = data.billdates;
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("dailySales");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "BillDate";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  let grandTotal = 0;
  let grandGross = 0;
  let grandDiscount = 0;
  let grandGst = 0;
  let outletWiseTotal = {};
  let outletWiseGross = {};
  let outletWiseDiscount = {};
  let outletWiseGst = {};
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.colSpan = 4;
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.colSpan = 4;
    th.innerHTML = element;
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
    outletWiseGross[element] = 0;
    outletWiseDiscount[element] = 0;
    outletWiseGst[element] = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.outlet == element) {
        outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
        outletWiseGross[element] += parseInt(el.gross);
        outletWiseDiscount[element] += parseInt(el.discount);
        outletWiseGst[element] += parseInt(el.GST);
      }
    });
    grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element]; //calculating totals for Total column
    grandGross += outletWiseGross[element];
    grandDiscount += outletWiseDiscount[element];
    grandGst += outletWiseGst[element];
  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  for (i = 0; i < outlets.length + 1; i++) { //here i am making the header as col-span
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Discount";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("discount"); //adding class to column discount
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "GST";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("gst"); //adding class to column gst
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Net Amount";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("netAmount"); //adding class to column Net Amount
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Gross Amount";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("grossAmount"); //adding class to column Gross Amount
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  }

  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = "Total";
  td.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(td);

  outlets.forEach(element => { // these are the table rows for each column
    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseGross[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseDiscount[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseGst[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);


  });
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandTotal.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandGst.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandDiscount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandGross.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);


  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  billdates.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = element;
    row.appendChild(td);

    let total = 0;
    let totalGross = 0;
    let totalDiscount = 0;
    let totalGST = 0;
    outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let ta = 0;
      let tg = 0;
      let tdi = 0;
      let tgst = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
          total += parseInt(d.amount);
          totalGross += parseInt(d.gross);
          totalDiscount += parseInt(d.discount);
          totalGST += parseInt(d.GST);
          ta = d.amount;
          tg = d.gross;
          tdi = d.discount;
          tgst = d.GST;
        }
      });

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tg.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tdi.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tgst.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = ta.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);




    });


    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = total.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalGST.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalDiscount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);



    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalGross.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);


    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
renderTable(formatedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="form-group  col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <label for="subCategoryCode">Filter Data :</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="To" id="To" readonly>
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu checkbox-menu allow-focus" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">

        <li><label> <input type="checkbox"
       value="Gross Amount"> Gross Amount
     </label></li>

        <li><label> <input type="checkbox"
       value="Discount"> Discount
     </label></li>

        <li><label> <input type="checkbox"
       value="GST"> GST
     </label></li>
        <li><label> <input type="checkbox"
       value="Net Amount"> Net Amount 
     </label></li>


      </ul>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="commonButton" id="save">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Go
     </button>
  </div>

</div>


<div align="left" class="table table-responsive" id="commonDvScroll">
  <table id="dailySales" class="maxWidthCommonTable"></table>
</div>
```

As my code is bit long so i have commented the lines where i am doing what in my JavaScript code to make it easier

I want to hide the columns on the basis of user selections
Any one out here help me out with some approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you use some classes like `grossAmount`, `discount`, `gst` and `netAmount` in the table header... That's a good thing.

It even would be better if those classes were added to the corresponding cells in each row. You could use those really easilly to show/hide the cells.

I achieved something **way more complicated** using something like 3 nested loops to show the cells based on the `index` of the header having a selected class.

I took the selected classes from the `#To` input, which is a coma separated list of words *close* to the classes needed to find the column indexes.

Note that it is far from optimal and efficient coding, but it works... And could be instructive to you. ;)

```
$("#save").on("click",function(){

  // Get the selected classes
  var classes = $("#To").val().replace(/\s+/g,"").split(",");

  // Hide cells
  $(".table thead tr:not(:first) th:not(:first-child)").hide();
  $(".table tbody tr td:not(:first-child)").hide();

  // Adjust thead first row colspans
  $(".table thead tr:first th:not(:first)").attr("colspan",classes.length);

  // For each classes selected
  for(i=0;i<classes.length;i++){
    //force 3 first letters to lowercase
    var classToShow = classes[i].substr(0,3).toLowerCase() + classes[i].substr(3);

    // For each element having the class
    $("."+classToShow).each(function(){
      var index = $(this).index();

      // Show selected cells in the thead
      $(".table thead tr:not(:first)").each(function(){
        $(this).find("th").eq(index).show();
      });

      // Show selected cells in the tbody
      $(".table tbody tr").each(function(){
        $(this).find("td").eq(index).show();
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```js
$("#save").on("click",function(){
  
  // Get the selected classes
  var classes = $("#To").val().replace(/\s+/g,"").split(",");
  
  // Hide cells
  $(".table thead tr:not(:first) th:not(:first-child)").hide();
  $(".table tbody tr td:not(:first-child)").hide();
  
  // Adjust thead first row colspans
  $(".table thead tr:first th:not(:first)").attr("colspan",classes.length);
  
  // For each classes selected
  for(i=0;i<classes.length;i++){
    //force 3 first letters to lowercase
    var classToShow = classes[i].substr(0,3).toLowerCase() + classes[i].substr(3);
    
    // For each element having the class
    $("."+classToShow).each(function(){
      var index = $(this).index();
      
      // Show selected cells in the thead
      $(".table thead tr:not(:first)").each(function(){
        $(this).find("th").eq(index).show();
      });
      
      // Show selected cells in the tbody
      $(".table tbody tr").each(function(){
        $(this).find("td").eq(index).show();
      });
    });
  }
});

// ======================= NOTHING CHANGED BELOW

$(".checkbox-menu").on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function() { // this one to select multiple options as check box
  $(this).closest("li").toggleClass("active", this.checked);
  var sList = "";
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      sList += $(this).val() + ","
    }
  });

  $("#To").val(sList.slice(0, -1));
});

$(document).on('click', '.allow-focus', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

var data = [{
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 490465,
    "discount": 839,
    "GST": 28465,
    "amount": 518212
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 99212,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 5567,
    "amount": 104801
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 131349,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 6676,
    "amount": 138151
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 594466,
    "discount": 591,
    "GST": 34374,
    "amount": 628358
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 109029,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 6062,
    "amount": 115113
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 127449,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 6511,
    "amount": 134107
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-06",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 167811,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 9968,
    "amount": 177866
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-06",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 62796,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3257,
    "amount": 66095
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 267398,
    "discount": 268,
    "GST": 15898,
    "amount": 283124
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 55381,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3383,
    "amount": 58789
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 64586,
    "discount": 6,
    "GST": 3285,
    "amount": 67886
  }
]

let formatData = function(data) {
  let billdates = [];
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
      billdates.push(element.billdate);
    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  return {
    data: data,
    billdates: billdates,
    outlets: outlets,

  };
};

let renderTable = function(data) {
  billdates = data.billdates;
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("dailySales");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "BillDate";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  let grandTotal = 0;
  let grandGross = 0;
  let grandDiscount = 0;
  let grandGst = 0;
  let outletWiseTotal = {};
  let outletWiseGross = {};
  let outletWiseDiscount = {};
  let outletWiseGst = {};
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.colSpan = 4;
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.colSpan = 4;
    th.innerHTML = element;
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
    outletWiseGross[element] = 0;
    outletWiseDiscount[element] = 0;
    outletWiseGst[element] = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.outlet == element) {
        outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
        outletWiseGross[element] += parseInt(el.gross);
        outletWiseDiscount[element] += parseInt(el.discount);
        outletWiseGst[element] += parseInt(el.GST);
      }
    });
    grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element]; //calculating totals for Total column
    grandGross += outletWiseGross[element];
    grandDiscount += outletWiseDiscount[element];
    grandGst += outletWiseGst[element];
  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  for (i = 0; i < outlets.length + 1; i++) { //here i am making the header as col-span
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Discount";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("discount"); //adding class to column discount
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "GST";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("gst"); //adding class to column gst
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Net Amount";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("netAmount"); //adding class to column Net Amount
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Gross Amount";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("grossAmount"); //adding class to column Gross Amount
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  }

  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = "Total";
  td.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(td);

  outlets.forEach(element => { // these are the table rows for each column
    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseGross[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseDiscount[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseGst[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);


  });
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandTotal.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandGst.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandDiscount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandGross.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);


  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  billdates.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = element;
    row.appendChild(td);

    let total = 0;
    let totalGross = 0;
    let totalDiscount = 0;
    let totalGST = 0;
    outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let ta = 0;
      let tg = 0;
      let tdi = 0;
      let tgst = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
          total += parseInt(d.amount);
          totalGross += parseInt(d.gross);
          totalDiscount += parseInt(d.discount);
          totalGST += parseInt(d.GST);
          ta = d.amount;
          tg = d.gross;
          tdi = d.discount;
          tgst = d.GST;
        }
      });

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tg.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tdi.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tgst.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = ta.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);




    });


    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = total.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalGST.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalDiscount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);



    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalGross.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);


    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
renderTable(formatedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="form-group  col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <label for="subCategoryCode">Filter Data :</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="To" id="To" readonly>
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu checkbox-menu allow-focus" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">

        <li><label> <input type="checkbox"
       value="Gross Amount"> Gross Amount
     </label></li>

        <li><label> <input type="checkbox"
       value="Discount"> Discount
     </label></li>

        <li><label> <input type="checkbox"
       value="GST"> GST
     </label></li>
        <li><label> <input type="checkbox"
       value="Net Amount"> Net Amount 
     </label></li>


      </ul>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="commonButton" id="save">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Go
     </button>
  </div>

</div>


<div align="left" class="table table-responsive" id="commonDvScroll">
  <table id="dailySales" class="maxWidthCommonTable"></table>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**

Here's an example on how to use classes to show/hide columns using the cell classes. I've made it on a *shortened version* of your table...

By the way, it is not a problem if the table is "dynamic" or not here... Since the show/hide action runs when the table is rendered. So all needed element exist and can be targeted on user triggered event.

I used the 4 columns classes you had... And 2 more: `selectable` to target all cells that potentially can be hidden/shown and `colspaned` to target the headers which will need a colspan attribute adjustment.

So as you can see below, it is much more efficient since there's only a simple loop to gather the values and corresponding class of each 4 checkboxes. I've placed those classes in a data attribute.

```js
var selections = $(".checkbox-menu :checkbox");
var filterData = $("#To");
var originalColspan = $(".colspaned").attr("colspan");

selections.on("change",function(){
  
  // Clear the "Filter Data" input
  filterData.val("");
  
  // Get the selected classe
  var classes = [];
  var values = [];
  selections.each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
      
      // Get the selected classe
      classes.push( "." + $(this).data("select") );
      
      // Value in the "filter Data" input
      values.push( $(this).val() );
    }
  });
  
  // Value in the "filter Data" input... If still useful (!)
  filterData.val(values.join(","));
  
  // Get how many selected
  var selectedAmount = classes.length;
  
  // If at least one selection
  if(selectedAmount>0){
  
    // Adjust headers colspan attr
    $(".colspaned").attr("colspan",selectedAmount);
    
    // Hide all cells
    $(".selectable").hide();
    
    // Show selected
    $(classes.join(",")).show();
  }
  
  // If no selection, show all cells
  else{
    $(".selectable").show();
    
    // Adjust headers colspan attr
    $(".colspaned").attr("colspan",originalColspan);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-group  col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <label for="subCategoryCode">Filter Data :</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="To" id="To" readonly>
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu checkbox-menu allow-focus" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">

        <li>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Gross Amount" data-select="grossAmount"> Gross Amount
          </label>
        </li>

        <li>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Discount" data-select="discount"> Discount
          </label>
        </li>

        <li>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="GST" data-select="gst"> GST
          </label>
        </li>
        
        <li>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Net Amount" data-select="netAmount"> Net Amount  
          </label>
        </li>


      </ul>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="commonButton" id="save">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Go
    </button>
  </div>

</div>


<div align="left" class="table table-responsive" id="commonDvScroll">
  <table id="dailySales" class="maxWidthCommonTable">
    <table id="dailySales" class="maxWidthCommonTable"><table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">BillDate</th>
          <th colspan="4" class="text-center colspaned">Total</th>
          
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
          </th>
          <th class="text-center grossAmount selectable">Gross Amount</th>
          <th class="text-center discount selectable">Discount</th>
          <th class="text-center gst selectable">GST</th>
          <th class="text-center netAmount selectable">Net Amount</th>
          
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">Total</th>
          <th class="text-right grossAmount selectable">21,69,942</th>
          <th class="text-right discount selectable">1,704</th>
          <th class="text-right gst selectable">1,23,446</th>
          <th class="text-right netAmount selectable">22,92,502</th>
          
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>2018-08-04</td>
        <td class="text-right grossAmount selectable">7,21,026</td>
        <td class="text-right discount selectable">839</td>
        <td class="text-right gst selectable">40,708</td>
        <td class="text-right netAmount selectable">7,61,164</td>
        
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>2018-08-05</td>
        <td class="text-right grossAmount selectable">8,30,944</td>
        <td class="text-right discount selectable">591</td>
        <td class="text-right gst selectable">46,947</td>
        <td class="text-right netAmount selectable">8,77,578</td>
        
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>2018-08-06</td>
          <td class="text-right grossAmount selectable">2,30,607</td>
          <td class="text-right discount selectable">0</td>
          <td class="text-right gst selectable">13,225</td>
          <td class="text-right netAmount selectable">2,43,961</td>
          
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2018-08-07</td>
          <td class="text-right grossAmount selectable">3,87,365</td>
          <td class="text-right discount selectable">274</td>
          <td class="text-right gst selectable">22,566</td>
          <td class="text-right netAmount selectable">4,09,799</td>
          
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: this one is very complicated though how can i achieve that by giving classes to the table rows also as i have already given to headers a you are talking about

Comment: I know... I used thoses classes. But it would be easier to have those classes on each cells too... So you would not need three nested loops. That's my point.

Comment: my point is suppose i have given classes to each cell so what approach should i follow then? to make this happen

Comment: It would then simply be `$(".netAmount").show()` and it would act on all cells one shot. (supposing you also add a class to "normally" hide them first... Like `$(".allCells").hide()`

Comment: You have to re-work your dynamic table creation in order to uses some classes. And to have them directly from the checkboxes (I had to remove spaces and to lowercase some letters...) I won't this this for you here... But if you got the idea, you can do it. ;)

Comment: hey sir on small doubt suppose i have a checkbox with option All so when user clicks on All i want to show full table

Comment: You could use those classes: `grossAmount`, `discount`, `gst`, `netAmount` and something like `allColumns`. So on checkbox check, use `allColumns` to hide them all, then use the relevant class to show if its checkbox is checked. The "all" checkbox simply would use the `allColumns` class to show them all. --- That would be much simpler and efficient.

Comment: i am trying to call the render table function inside save click if checkbox is equals to `All` it it is displaying blank

Comment: I've made a better demo for you... To show how to use the classes.

Comment: You will get a faster answer writing a new question with all relevant details.

Comment: hey sir whenever you get some time please check out my post i am really stuck with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846400/appended-new-row-is-not-behaving-like-previous-one-row

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way to do this is by adding column data to your table, like so:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead></thead>
  <colgroup>
    <col style="background-color:yellow; visibility: collapse;">
    <col id="total" span="4" style="background-color:red">
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">BillDate</th>
      <th colspan="4" class="text-center">Total</th>
      <th colspan="4" class="text-center">JAYANAGAR</th>
      <th colspan="4" class="text-center">MALLESHWARAM</th>
      <th colspan="4" class="text-center">KOLAR</th>
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

BUT there's a [chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=174167) that prevents the visibility attribute from having any effect on cols or colgroups.

I would then avoid using a table, and build the table manually with regular divs, and group columns together.

Comment: sir my table is dynamic and all of my headers are also dynamic now it is `jayanagar``malleshwaram` and `kolar` but in futer the may increase on the basis of user selection

Comment: Then the cols can be dynamic too :) But this will only work once the Chromium bug is fixed

Comment: so sir any other approach,how can i achieve what i am trying to?

Comment: Yes, build the table manually, meaning - use regular divs and style them yourself. Build it grouped by columns instead of rows. That way you can control the columns directly.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through these links. As per my view you can avoid the select box (if you are using the select box value just for hide the column). You can use the approach mentioned in below links.

```
`https://codepen.io/feger/pen/eDybC`
```

[show / hide table columns using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970382/show-hide-table-columns-using-jquery)

https://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-options

You can use .hide() Hide the matched elements.

Comment: i have already seen this one but here my table is dynamic and i want to hide on the basis of second header which contains the `Amount types`